# Wordpress XML-RPC with Java

Tags: java, wordpress

Is there any way to get posts and information from a Wordpress blog form Java code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an XML-RPC client, you can use the Apache [XML-RPC library](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/)

Here a list of [Wordpress supported API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API).

And finally a [short tutorial](http://wordpress.rintcius.nl/post/2006/07) to get you started.

Comment: How to include this library in a Android Project and how to use it. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Java library for doing so:

https://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/

it includes [sample code here](https://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/wiki/ExampleCode).